# How can one capture the length of time it takes for an EC2-based job to run in Datadog?

Tags: analytics, jobs, datadog

I have a job that runs several times a day in an EC2 instance. I have a Datadog integration with AWS and the agent on the instance. However, I'm unsure of how best to measure the average time it takes to run.

If I take a time series, it won't capture the average duration because there's not a clear way to measure the "start vs end."

Any ideas?